# What is needed to generate kerberos keytab file on windows?

Tags: windows, hbase, kerberos, keytab, ktpass

I was looking for answer to above question on different web sites but in the every case there was how to generate keytab file. I need keytab to get hbase connection which contains kerberos authentication.

Comment: Hi; If we've answered your question please mark it as such which will verify it to others in the community; otherwise please let us know if any.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to generate a keytab on Windows, you need to be running some version of Kerberos which talks back to a Directory server.  On Windows, by far the most prevalent example of this is Active Directory, which has Kerberos support built-in.  You'll need to create the keytab on a Windows server joined to the Active Directory domain, using the ktpass command to actually create the keytab.

Keytab generation syntax example:

```
ktpass -out centos1-dev-local.keytab -mapUser krbCentos@DEV.LOCAL +rndPass -mapOp set +DumpSalt -crypto AES256-SHA1 -ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL -princ HTTP/centos1.dev.local@DEV.LOCAL
```

The above command example successfully creats a keytab for use in an AD domain named DEV.LOCAL.  Note: notice the use of the randomize password syntax (+rndPass).  In my opinion, there is no need to specify a password in the keytab creation command syntax.   Instead, it's better to allow the password to be randomized - that provides much better security since it prevents anyone from being able to manually logon as the AD account surreptitiously and bypass the keytab.

For additional reference, I highly suggest you read my article on Kerberos keytab creation on the Windows platform on Microsoft Technet which greatly expands on what I said here:  [Kerberos Keytabs – Explained](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36470.kerberos-keytabs-explained.aspx).  I frequently go back and edit it based on questions I see here in this forum.

Comment: And where can I get ktpass.exe on non-Server Windows 10?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski - ktpass will not run on Windows 10, that only runs on Windows Server (i.e., Windows Server 2008/2012/2016/2019).

Comment: I am having a very hard time understanding the -mapUser and -princ relationship. Why cant both be the same. I just need a keytab file to get a kerberos ticket from Active Directory KDC using kinit command example (c:\> kinit -kt aduser.keytab aduser@REALM )    so why do I need to bother about mapping two different userids using -mapUser and -princ. Also want to keep the existing password in AD using -pass xyz12345 .

Comment: the -princ is the SPN, the -mapUser is the AD account name.